# Copying a user specific file to the desktop during login

Tags: windows, powershell, gpo

I want to have a specific file copied to a user's desktop during login. Ideally, I would like to have one script that will "detect" the user logging in and copy a file with that user's name (i.e. "User1.txt"). Would this be possible, or would I need a script per user I want to do this with?

Comment: Yes, Windows has the concept of a logon script that will be executed when the user logs on. You could then use the `$env:user` variable to get their username and copy the required file.

Comment: Search for "group policy" and "login script" and you will find many guides as how to set that up. The rest is easy using the right environment variable as @MarkWragg pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the task schedule to run a script file when the user logons on

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have a domain, then go to group policies and set up a logon script that will copy the UserName.txt to his desktop.

```
Copy-item -Path "File path" -Destination %systemDrive%\%userProfile%\Desktop
```